# jQuery hover animation on single element in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, animation, hover

I have an array of results, all with the same classes that is repeated several times in a list of result. I have setup a jQuery hover animation to occur when you hover over one of the results, however currently when I hover over one results, the animation happens to all results.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".hover").hover(
        function(){
            jQuery(".agent").animate({top: '-=32px'},300, 'easeOutBack');
            jQuery(".fav").delay(150).animate({top: '-=32px'},300, 'easeOutBack');
            jQuery(".more_details").delay(300).animate({top: '-=32px'},300, 'easeOutBack');
        },
        function(){
            jQuery(".agent,.fav,.more_details").animate({top: '+=32px'},150);
    }
    );                              
});
```

Is it possible to single out one item in my array and just have the animation occur to the item being hovered over??

Thanks

Comment: You need to get the `.agent`, `.fav` and `.more_details` elements relative to the element being hovered over. If you can post your HTML structure I can show you how to do this.

Comment: why not use `$(this)` within the function. if `.agent` `.fav` and `.more_details` are children elements, then why not do `$(this).children().animate({...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the element with class `hover` is parent of the rest of element, pass the current object as [context in selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".hover").hover(
        function(){
            jQuery(".agent", this).animate({top: '-=32px'},300, 'easeOutBack');
            jQuery(".fav", this ).delay(150).animate({top: '-=32px'},300, 'easeOutBack');
            jQuery(".more_details", this).delay(300).animate({top: '-=32px'},300, 'easeOutBack');
        },
        function(){
            jQuery(".agent,.fav,.more_details").animate({top: '+=32px'},150);
    }
    );                              
});
```